# Single-entry visa from the Italian embassy

Tags: italy, tourist-visas, schengen-visas

I applied for a Schengen visa via the Italian consulate  and got a single-entry type C ”stati Schengen” Visa as I am traveling to Florence on holiday.

However I would like to visit my friends during my stay who live in Oslo and Copenhagen before my exit, as my trip is 15 days. I am unsure if I can go to these countries as they are not part of the EU but seem to be a part of the Schengen area. Please advise as I don’t want any trouble at all!

Comment: Nitpick: Denmark is a part of the EU.

Comment: they're both in the Schengen area and treated as internal flights. Denmark is also in the EU. As long as you don't leave the Schengen area you'll be fine

Comment: Thanks alot for the responses, i feel alot better knowing i can travel to Oslo and Norway with no trouble. I will just ensure i have my itinerary ready for customs. Yes Italy is my first point of entry and i will be in florence for a few days.

Answer (score 5):

Because your visa is valid for "stati Schengen," which means "Schengen states," it authorizes you to travel to any Schengen country after you enter the Schengen area (see footnote 1).

With a single-entry Schengen visa, once you're in the Schengen area, you can travel freely between the countries for which it is valid.  You must be certain that you do not leave the Schengen area, because your visa becomes invalid at that point (see footnote 2).

- Do not book a flight with a transfer in the UK, Ireland, Bulgaria, Romania, Cyprus, Croatia, or any other non-Schengen country.

Readers with different itineraries may also want to keep in mind the following.

- Do not go to Andorra
- Do not travel by land to or from Greece.

There are probably other places to be careful of.

Non-EU Schengen countries, such as Norway, are fully part of the Schengen area, so traveling to Norway from Italy would be no different from traveling to Sweden from Italy, at least from the standpoint of passport controls and visas (once again, subject to limitation in the "valid for" entry, which this visa does not have).

---

Footnote 1: Annex VII of the [Schengen Visa Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02009R0810-20160412) specifies at paragraph 1.1 that the *VALID FOR* heading "indicates the territory in which the visa holder is entitled to travel."

Footnote 2: Annex VII specifies in the fourth paragraph of section 3 that "The visa is no longer valid when the total number of exits made by the visa holder equals the number of authorised entries, even if the visa holder has not used up the number of days authorised by the visa."

Comment: Can you add more to your "Greece by land" comment? I was under the impression so far that Greece came under Schengen.

Comment: @hojusaram Greece is indeed part of the Schengen area.  It does not share a land border with any other Schengen country, however, so traveling between Greece and another Schengen country by land requires exiting and reentering the Schengen area.  Direct flights, however, are fine for someone with limited entries.

Comment: Oh I see. Traveling by direct ferry e.g. from Italy should also be fine, right?

Comment: @hojusaram I think so, but I have no experience with it so I don't know for sure.  If there were a ferry that called in Italy and Greece and some non-Schengen port then that would probably require passport control.  A ferry that calls only in Schengen ports should not involve passport control.

Answer (score 3):

Your visa is for the Schengen Area, not for the EU, so it gives you permission to enter the Schengen Area - and when you're inside the Schengen Area you can travel freely within it. So yes, with your Schengen visa you can visit both Denmark and Norway as long as you travel within the area, i.e. you can't take a plane via e.g. the UK (still in the EU, but not in Schengen).

You need to make sure that Italy remains the main destination for your trip, or you risk accusations of visa fraud.

Comment: Travelling via the UK is not travelling within Schengen - the OP would be exiting Schengen (although not the EU)

Comment: @Traveller ...until the UK itself exits the EU.  But yes, the suggestion that one can fly from Italy to Norway or Denmark via the UK with a single-entry Schengen visa is seriously mistaken.  As soon as the traveler receives and exit stamp in Italy, the visa is invalid and the traveler will be unable to reenter the Schengen area at the destination.

Comment: That was a very unfortunate typo. I always meant to warn against travelling through the UK (and provide an example of a country in the EU but not in Schengen, just opposite Norway - and I know that the UK will leave the EU next year, so the example is only valid for ~8½ month).